# Artsy api to get information about artists is pretty much empty

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a python program that requests information about artists from the Artsy api. 
https://api.artsy.net/api/artists
This is what they say to use under their API docs; however, I can only see 5 different artists, and they don't have names. If they do have names it's something like '00101000'I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and I can't find a lot of information on this api.

```
import json
import requests


headers = {"X-Xapp-Token" : token}
url = "https://api.artsy.net/api/artists"
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

data = json.loads(r.text)
for element in data['_embedded']['artists']:
    for i in range(len(data['_embedded']['artists'])):
        id = data['_embedded']['artists'][i]['id']
        artist = url+"/"+str(id)
```

https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/5723c839139b2113a8000619
that is one of the links that my code prints. They are all similar.

https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/4d8b92b34eb68a1b2c0003f4
This is the one from the example.

I'm just not sure how to get the information I need